# Limiting input size with std::setw in std::cin

Tags: c++, stream, limit, cin

Let's say I have sample code:

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> std::setw(4) >> s;
std::cout << s;
```

Now for input `abcdef` the result will be `abc` and for `abc` it will be `abc` too. The question is how can I check whether the string was split in the middle due to the limit or the result string is the actual one? I need to know whether the input fits or some data was skipped.

Comment: Why not take the entire string as input and use some substring variation ?

Comment: Because it may not fit into the memory and it's a waste of resources.

Comment: If you clear the string' content afterward it will be a very marginal ressource lost.

Comment: hmm..how about using getchar or its c++ equivalent istream::get ? While reading input if you hit feof that means no more charav=cters left, if not, you have read incomplete data

Comment: JGab: Yeah sure, it's very marginal if I load few gigabytes of data.
ArunMu: I'm looking for something smarter than that.

Comment: @SebastianNowak: I doubt if it can be done any better as your input is a stream..lets see

Comment: Is the remaining input redundant or will you read again? If it's redundant, I wonder why you even need to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I know that the stream's width is considered when reading into a `char*` I wasn't aware that it is also considered when reading into a `std::string`. Assuming it is, reading would stop under three conditions:

1. The stream is completely read in which case `eof()` is set.
2. The next character is a space.
3. The number of characters which need to be read are read.

That is, you can check `in.eof()` and `std::isspace(in.peek()`.  Well, is there is a funny `std::ctype<char>` facet used by the stream you'd really need to use

```
std::isspace(in.getloc(),
    std::char_traits<char>::to_char_type(in.peek()));
```

Comment: Aren't the parameters the other way around? - [std::isspace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isspace)

Comment: @0x499602D2: that is quite possible: I didn't check the standard or the documentation when typing in the answer.